# Downloading Windows SDK 7.1 help contents to offline PC

Tags: winapi, offline-browsing

Does anyone know how to download the help contents of the Windows SDK 7.1 to a computer **not** connected to the internet? So far I've come across [this](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/), but it doesn't have a Windows SDK or Platform SDK item listed.

This link came from the [MSDN Blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/06/07/downloading-the-windows-sdk-7-1-documentation-for-offline-viewing.aspx), which is not very helpful since they ask us to connect the computer to the internet (which I can't do), and the comments comprise of people complaining about Microsoft's incompetence.

Comment: Actually, a couple of comments offer workarounds.

Comment: OK I took a look again and found this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thehelpguy/archive/2010/04/30/using-a-common-network-share-for-vs-2010-help-updates.aspx
Is that what you meant? I couldn't find anything about the Windows SDK other than the help downloader link in the question.